# How to use a third party non serializable object in a UDAF?

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization

I have a class with a third party non serializable property that I need to send to a UDAF that use one method of this class.

I can't add the "implements Serializable" beacuse the non serializable property, and I cant do a child class wrapper because the property nees a parameter in their constructor...

Any idea?

```
public class ClassWithNoSerializableProperty implements Serializable {

    private NoSerializable property;

    public ClassWithNoSerializableProperty (String text) {
        property = new NoSerializable(text);
    }

}
public class NoSerializable {

    protected String text;

    public NoSerializable(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could mark it as `transient` to exclude it from serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this class to wrap `NoSerializable`'s constructor

```
SerializedWrapper<NoSerializable> property = new SerializedWrapper(() -> new NoSerializable(text));
// call this to use it.
property.get();

/**
 * Makes an unserializable class serializable through lazy initialization.
 */
public class SerializedWrapper<T> implements Serializable {

    private SerializedConstructor<T> constructor;
    private transient T instance;

    /**
     * Creates a serializable wrapper for something.
     */
    public SerializedWrapper(SerializedConstructor<T> constructor) {
        this.constructor = constructor;
    }

    /**
     * Gets or creates an instance of T.
     */
    public T get() {
        if (instance == null){
            instance = constructor.get();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}

/**
 * Dummy interface so we don't have to do (Consumer<T> & Serializable)
 */
public interface SerializedConstructor<T> implements Serializable, Consumer<T> {}
```